# Juju not seeing the MaaS slaves... at least not after some time?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

At our company are doing a project where we want to start doing Juju, MaaS and OpenStack. All in all we are satisfied, but we have one major problem that is setting us back. We haven't seemed to find out where the problem lies - with juju or MaaS.

We have set up a MaaS master with ubuntu 12.10 - and we use 12.04 on the MaaS slaves. We have one bootstrap slave and 6 slaves for OpenStack...

In the beginning everything seems to work fine - getting all slaves in ready state in MaaS and deploying with juju also seems to work as expected. We deploy a whole openstack environment. But at some point (this has been experienced 3-4 times after redoing it all over again) Juju will not see new MaaS slaves and when we want to add units or other juju charms on new nodes those will not be seen by Juju. They are stated as Ready in MaaS, but Juju does not see them, and when we use juju deploy  the charm just will say pending and machine will say pending, not picking the ready nodes from maas. I can see that juju version in the slaves is 0.6 but i can see there is a newer version. Will it work with the newer version?

Comment: Using 13.04 on the MaaS master and Juju version 0.6 on bootstrap node seems to work as expected. I can deploy charms on MaaS nodes and delete them again and terminate the machine and start over again with no problem...

Comment: If juju says pending in the `juju status` command, I think it means it does indeed see the machine, but for me Juju says something is pending until the install on the machine finishes and reboots into the install. If you connect a screen on the actual physical machine, what do you see? (I know it's probably a bit inconvenient, but its probably the quickest way to know what is happening).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in that version of Juju (0.5) - the problem does not occur in newer versions.